# Cypress: How to get value of div (mixing up async and sync code)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cypress

I have a div with the following html

```html
<div data-cy="pop" style="margin-right:5px;">12,300</div>
```

I am trying to get `12,3001` convert it to a int and save the value for use in another function.

I am getting this error

> `cy.then()` failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
> The value you synchronously returned was: 12300

Here is my code to get the value.

```js
cy.elem('pop').invoke('text').then((num) => {
  const res = parseInt(num.replaceAll(',',''))
  return res
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Bit of an edge-case, **TLDR:** `return cy.wrap(res)`.

If I run this as a minimal test for your code, it passes

```js
const num = "12,300";
cy.wrap(num).then((numAsString) => {
  const numAsInt = parseInt(numAsString.replace(",", ""));
  return numAsInt
})
.then(num => {
  cy.log(num)   // logs 12300    ✅ 
})
```

If I add an async line `cy.wait(5000)` (for example), it fails

```js
const num = "12,300";
cy.wrap(num).then((numAsString) => {
  const numAsInt = parseInt(numAsString.replace(",", ""));
  cy.wait(5000)
  return numAsInt
})
.then(num => {
  cy.log(num)                    ❌
})
```

If I then `cy.wrap()` the result, it passes again

```js
const num = "12,300";
cy.wrap(num).then((numAsString) => {
  const numAsInt = parseInt(numAsString.replace(",", ""));
  cy.wait(5000)
  return cy.wrap(numAsInt)
})
.then(num => {
  cy.log(num)   // logs 12300    ✅ 
})
```

Theoretically your code should pass, but if you have another command inside the `.then()` that could be causing it.

Or possible the `cy.elem('pop')` is causing it.

---

For reference, this is Cypress' own test for the error

```js
describe("errors", {defaultCommandTimeout: 100}, () => {

  beforeEach(function () {
    this.logs = [];

    cy.on("log:added", (attrs, log) => {
      this.lastLog = log;
      this.logs?.push(log);
    });

    return null;
  });

  it("throws when mixing up async + sync return values", function (done) {
    cy.on("fail", (err) => {
      const { lastLog } = this;

      assertLogLength(this.logs, 1)
      expect(lastLog.get("error")).to.eq(err);
      expect(err.message).to.include(
        "`cy.then()` failed because you are mixing up async and sync code."
      );

      done();
    });

    cy.then(() => {
      cy.wait(5000);

      return "foo";
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are attempting to pass the value of your parsed int into the another function.

One way to save the value of something is with an [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Alias). To do that you will need to use the `.as()`.

```js
cy.elem('pop')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((num) => { return parseInt(num.replaceAll(',','')) })
  .as('num')

// later down in your code
cy.get('@num')
  .then(number => {
    functionYouWantToPassYourNumber(number)
  })
```